# jQuery elastic menu

Tags: jquery, menu, mouseover

I have a problem with an elastic menu I'm trying to create with jQuery. It looks (almost) good in Safari (there's a little shaking on the right of the menu though when mouse hover). But in Chrome and Firefox, the last menu (contact) sometimes jumps to the next line. I'm pretty new to jQuery and I can't manage to see the problem...

You can see it in action in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wally/jRMZM/1/)

Here's my code:

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){


var bouton = $('#menu li a'),
vitesse = 300;

bouton.hover(function(){
    var leParent = $(this).parent();
    leParent.stop().animate({ width: "40%" }, vitesse )
    .siblings().stop().animate({ width: "20%" }, vitesse );
    });

bouton.mouseout(function(){
    var leParent = $(this).parent();
    leParent.stop().animate({ width: "25%" }, vitesse )
    .siblings().stop().animate({ width: "25%" }, vitesse );
    });


});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Produits</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
html, body{margin:0;
padding:0;}


#menu{
padding:0;
width:80%;
margin:10px auto;
list-style-type:none;
}

#menu li{
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:25%;
float:left;
text-align:center;
background-color:#C03;
}


#menu li a{
border-left:1px solid white;
padding:10px 0;
color:#FFF;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are animating floating elements. When the dont fit inside your container, they display below.

You should leave some room while animating.

Do this:

```
#menu {
     text-align: center;
}
```

to make it center.

Remove:

```
#menu li {
    float: left;
}
```

And add:

```
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And change the width of your elements to 24% and the shrinked button size to 19%.

Finally make sure you remove all spaces between li elements.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#">Produits</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now it should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/jRMZM/2/

**You could always calculate the percentages yourself in a window resize event handler and make sure you do Math.floor() on the percentage calulation.**

**EDIT:**
http://jsfiddle.net/zWCf8/3/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't understand why they don't always fit inside my container with a percentage of 40%, 20% , 20% 20% when a button is rollover. Also, if I use 24% for normal state, I will have a 4% space on the right of the container...

Comment: Different browsers render floating point values differently.If you want to control this you should calculate your percentages yourself after measuring the destination widths.

Comment: The 4% space is because you did'nt remove the line breaks between the li elements. (the <!--
--> thing)

Comment: Ok I did that but see what I mean by extra 4% (the yellow bg for the container): http://jsfiddle.net/Wally/zWCf8/1/ + the right border of the "contact" button is moving much more with these percentages...

Comment: I you dont want a margin, you should calculate your percentages:http://jsfiddle.net/zWCf8/3/